# Best way to get feedback on open sourced project

Tags: cocoa, open-source

What is the best way to open source a project I would like help on? I'm aware of source forge, but is there some way to advertise "I'm a newbie looking to improve my coding skills, so here is a working project I'm uploading in hopes of learning how to code better?"  I currently have a Cocoa program I wrote that works fine, but I'm certain there are inefficiencies and leaks in my code that I will never know about unless someone with more experience points them out.

Comment: send me a link I'll beta test it

Answer (score 0):

Judging from my experience, if your project is considered to be useful, people will start submitting bug reports and patches by themselves. If that happens, get in touch with your submitters, offer them write access to the code base, distribute responsibility.

That way, you'll learn a lot about coding and, more importantly, team management.

That having said, why don't you participate in existing projects in order to improve your coding skills? Reading other people's code will boost your capabilities far more than just writing your own stuff.

Comment: is perfectly right. Not the implementation counts, but the idea. If the idea is good, people will get interested. On related comment: Sourceforge's dead, use [github](http://github.com/), the community is great and will readily help you.